# Suddenly got alert when trying to login to admin panel of wordpress

Tags: php, iis

Suddenly starts receiving alert when trying to login to wordpress admin panel. Hosting is on IIS server. It is type of alert prompt box given by firefox browser only with following text:

```
To display this page, Firefox must send information that will repeat any action (such as a search or order confirmation) that was performed earlier.
```

Wordpress admin login is the core functionality of wordpress. I didn't make any change in core files. Please suggest how can i solve this.

I already checked this one (To display this page, Firefox must send information that will repeat any action (such as a search or order confirmation) that was performed earlier)!

Anybody please help?

No change did on server side. It was working before that fine.

> Update:- I spent little time with server guy and we have checked there
>   is not any redirection rule present on IIS server. Only one binding between http & https request setup and one url rewriting rule is there, as below:-

````
<rule name="wordpress" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
    <match url="*" />
        <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
</rule>```
````

Comment: This happens when you refresh a page that is the result of a POST request. The previous operation might have been an incomplete form submit and you might have hit the refresh or browser reload button.

Comment: @Chittaranjan thanks for your reply but it doesn't like that. I didn't hit browser refresh button. It might be something server side. Could you please help?

Comment: Welcome to [wordpress.se]. I hope you find the answer(s) you are looking for. Our site is different from most - if you have not done so yet, consider checking out the [tour](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tour) and [help center](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help) to find out how things work.